# JS Поменять местами блоки див

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Доброго дня, подскажите пож. У меня есть два блока и скрипт, который определяет из какой страны зашли, как мне менять местами блок Беларусь и блок Россия в зависимости с какой страны зашли, например зашли из России значит должно быть так : Россия > Беларусь и наоборот?

```js
var $strana;
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    if(response.country == "RU") {
  document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "inline";
 document.getElementById("rln").style.color="#2987ac";
 document.getElementById("bel").style.display = "none";

 $strana='ru'; 
    }
    else if(response.country == "BY") {
        document.getElementById("bel").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("rln").style.color="#2987ac";
  document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "none";
  
  
 $strana='by'; 
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("enln").style.color="#2987ac";
  
 $strana='by'; 
    }

}, "jsonp");

function myFunction() {
 
if ($strana!="by") 
{
 alert('тут код перехода');
 $strana='by';
}
 else 
{
    document.getElementById("bel").style.display = "inline";
 document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "inline";
 document.getElementById("aclb").style.color="#2987ac";
 document.getElementById("art").style.color="#2987ac";
 document.getElementById("r_phone").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("b_phone").style.color="#2987ac";
 document.images["art"].src = 'assets/template/img/arrow_href.png';

}

}

function myFunction2() {
if ($strana!="ru") 
{
 alert('тут код перехода');
 $strana='ru';
}
else{
    document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "inline";
 document.getElementById("bel").style.display = "inline";
 document.getElementById("aclr").style.color="#2987ac";
 document.getElementById("art").style.color="#2987ac";
 document.getElementById("b_phone").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("r_phone").style.color="#2987ac";
 document.images["art"].src = 'assets/template/img/arrow_href.png';
}
}
```

```css
.rightCenter{
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-family: Arial Narrow;
    font-size: 8.9pt;
 height:34px;
}
.active-link{
transition: all 0.4s;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#bel{
    width: 51px;
    float: left;
}
#russ{
 width:50px;
 float:left;
 margin-left:3px;
}

.arrow_top{
vertical-align: middle;
float:left;
width:20px;
  height:20px
}
.arrow_top:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightCenter">
<div id="bel" onClick="myFunction()">   
  <a href="#" class="active-link" id="aclb">БЕЛАРУСЬ</a>
  <div class="rightBottom"  id="b_phone">
   +3-211-111-111-11
  </div>
</div>
     
<img src="http://wishbone.io/images/right.png" class="arrow_top" id="art" >

<div id="russ" onClick="myFunction2()" >
 <a href="#" class="active-link" id="aclr">РОССИЯ</a> 
  <div class="rightBottom" id="r_phone" >
 +7-985-698-52-31
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Имхо достаточно добавить такого кусочка кода, который перемещает русскую локацию в начало родителя

```
//begin
if (response.country == "RU") {
    $('#russ').prependTo('.rightCenter');
    $('.arrow_top').insertAfter('#russ');
}
//end
```

Результирующий код

```js
$(function() {
  var $strana;
  $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {

    //begin
    if (response.country == "RU") {
      $('#russ').prependTo('.rightCenter');
      $('.arrow_top').insertAfter('#russ');
    }
    //end

    if (response.country == "RU") {
      document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "inline";
      document.getElementById("rln").style.color = "#2987ac";
      document.getElementById("bel").style.display = "none";

      $strana = 'ru';
    } else if (response.country == "BY") {
      document.getElementById("bel").style.display = "inline";
      document.getElementById("rln").style.color = "#2987ac";
      document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "none";


      $strana = 'by';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "inline";
      //document.getElementById("enln").style.color = "#2987ac";

      $strana = 'by';
    }

  }, "jsonp");

  function myFunction() {

    if ($strana != "by") {
      alert('тут код перехода');
      $strana = 'by';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("bel").style.display = "inline";
      document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "inline";
      document.getElementById("aclb").style.color = "#2987ac";
      document.getElementById("art").style.color = "#2987ac";
      document.getElementById("r_phone").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("b_phone").style.color = "#2987ac";
      document.images["art"].src = 'assets/template/img/arrow_href.png';

    }

  }

  function myFunction2() {
    if ($strana != "ru") {
      alert('тут код перехода');
      $strana = 'ru';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("russ").style.display = "inline";
      document.getElementById("bel").style.display = "inline";
      document.getElementById("aclr").style.color = "#2987ac";
      document.getElementById("art").style.color = "#2987ac";
      document.getElementById("b_phone").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("r_phone").style.color = "#2987ac";
      document.images["art"].src = 'assets/template/img/arrow_href.png';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.rightCenter {
  float: left;
  width: 210px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  font-family: Arial Narrow;
  font-size: 8.9pt;
  height: 34px;
}
.active-link {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#bel {
  width: 51px;
  float: left;
}
#russ {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
.arrow_top {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px
}
.arrow_top:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightCenter">
  <div id="bel" onClick="myFunction()">
    <a href="#" class="active-link" id="aclb">БЕЛАРУСЬ</a>
    <div class="rightBottom" id="b_phone">
      +3-211-111-111-11
    </div>
  </div>

  <img src="http://wishbone.io/images/right.png" class="arrow_top" id="art">

  <div id="russ" onClick="myFunction2()">
    <a href="#" class="active-link" id="aclr">РОССИЯ</a> 
    <div class="rightBottom" id="r_phone">
      +7-985-698-52-31
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```